# Why do some rectangular lattices turn into cubic lattices upon heating?

Tags: phase-transition, lattice-model

Lattices that are rhombic or rectangular have been known to expand in the two shorter axes directions when heated until a cubic structure is reached before expanding linearly in all directions. Why is that? This is an example of a continuous phase transition (aka 2nd order). Stated inversely, why is it rectangular instead of cubic to begin with?